# Laravel API secure way to get list of users

Tags: laravel-5, oauth, oauth-2.0, jquery-select2, laravel-passport

I need to get a list of users with email through API access in Laravel and I'm trying to figure out the best way to allow access to that particular route for only the 'staff' role set using the silber/bouncer package. I've considered OAuth2 using Laravel Passport but it seems like too much extra work to get a list to be rendered in a simple select2 field in the admin section, however exposing the entire list of users through an unguarded route is not acceptable. Is there no light-weight alternative to OAuth2?

Comment: roles and rights (authorization) https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization. You can also create roles and rights as tables and give them a relationship to the user table

Comment: @ThomasMoors The issue when using a gate in an API route is that a user will be null if not authenticated using basic, digest or OAuth.

Comment: Have a look at JWT https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth After many considerations I have chosen this for my API security. It's easy to set up and simple in it's design. It may even become a new standard.